# Execute Query not updating records/data

Tags: sql, database, oracle, database-connection, executequery

I'm using the database utility Execute Query to experiment with Oracle SQL (10g).

My problem is that even after successfully executing a `CREATE TABLE` and an `INSERT`, the records are not shown when opening the data inspector.

Here is what I run:

```
DROP TABLE Customer;

CREATE TABLE Customer (
    CustomerNr INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    LastName    VARCHAR2(50),
    FirstName   VARCHAR2(50)
);

INSERT INTO Customer VALUES (1, 'Example', 'Joe');
```

The table is listed correctly:

[image]

Screenshot 1

However, no records are listed in the data tab:
[image]
[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnQsh.png)

`SELECT * FROM Customer;` can be executed successfully, but nothing is returned.

**If I disconnect from the database and connect again, the data is loaded properly.**

`SELECT * FROM Customer;` now also returns the inserted record correctly.

Is this a bug in Execute Query? Am I doing something wrong? What could I try to fix this?

PS: Please edit my post to include the images as I don't have the reputation to add images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the data inspector is running in a different database session to where you're doing the work. DDL statements (like `create table`) do implicit commits so the new table will be visible everywhere immediately. DML statements (like `insert`) do not (usually, by default, though some clients will based on settings), so the newly inserted data will not be visible in any other sessions.

In short... issue a `commit` in the same session as the `insert` to make it visible.

Disconnecting and reconnecting is also implicitly committing, which is why the data is visible after you've done that.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem! I also found an "auto commit" option in Execute Query.

Answer (score 0):

```
DB::connection('DB1')->update("UPDATE TABLE t1 SET t1.column_name = (SELECT column_name FROM DB2.TABLE2 t2 WHERE t1.primary_id = t2.foriegn_id)");
```

In my case, on Oracle SQL. Remember, `DB::beingTranstion()` needs to be removed.